# Installing CMake package config files for MacOS frameworks

Tags: macos, cmake

I created a versioned MacOS framework with CMake and stumbled over the question where to install the package config files `sample-config.cmake`, `sample-config-version.cmake`, `sample-exports.cmake`, `sample-exports-release.cmake`.

The framework is versioned so the structure is roughly as follows:

```
<sample.framework>
   |-- Headers                 # link to Versions/Current/Headers
   |-- Resources               # link to Versions/Current/Resources
   +-- Versions
       |-- Current             # link to B
       +-- B
           |-- Headers
           +-- Resources
               |-- CMake
               +-- Info.plist
```

I use CMakes `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` macros to generate a package config file from a template `sample-config.cmake.in` with the content

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/sample-export.cmake")
```

CMake does not mention versioned frameworks and recommends to install the files into the directory `Resources/CMake`.

I did so by calling

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/sample-config.cmake"
  DESTINATION sample.framework/Resources/CMake
  COMPONENT development
)
```

The generated file looks like this:

```
####### Expanded from @PACKAGE_INIT@ by configure_package_config_file() #######
####### Any changes to this file will be overwritten by the next CMake run ####
####### The input file was sample-config.cmake.in                            ########

get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)

macro(set_and_check _var _file)
  set(${_var} "${_file}")
  if(NOT EXISTS "${_file}")
    message(FATAL_ERROR "File or directory ${_file} referenced by variable ${_var} does not exist !")
  endif()
endmacro()

macro(check_required_components _NAME)
  foreach(comp ${${_NAME}_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    if(NOT ${_NAME}_${comp}_FOUND)
      if(${_NAME}_FIND_REQUIRED_${comp})
        set(${_NAME}_FOUND FALSE)
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro()

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/sample-export.cmake")
```

**Error:**

There's a difference in the generated config file whether I install those files to `Resources/CMake` or to `Versions/B/Resources/CMake` although both point to the same directory.

When installing via the `Resources` link to `Resources/CMake` the call to set `PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR` is generated as

```
`get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)`
```

but when installing via `Versions/B/Resources/CMake` it is generated as

```
`get_filename_component(PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../../" ABSOLUTE)`
```

As a consequence of this the package cannot be found by `find_package(sample CONFIG)` when installing to `Versions/B/Resources/CMake`.

Did anybody was facing this error before?

Thanks for any input on this.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to resolve this?

Comment: @user3667089 unfortunately there is no real solution to this issue as CMake has some issues with determining the package config file location when symbolic links are involved. See the answer to the CMake [thread](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/installing-cmake-package-config-files-for-macos-frameworks/849).